# mklink folders from Windows server to AIX

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-command-prompt, aix, symbolic-link, symlink

We need to make a softlink to other server on AIX and when doing accordingly to guide in cmd occurs an error

```
mklink /D \\10.0.0.10\folder C:\folder
```

and it returns - **The request is not supported**

But vice versa

```
mklink /D C:\folder \\10.0.0.10\folder
```

it says - symbolic link created for C:/folder .......

What can be the issue here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

symlink is a filesystem feature. The windows command `mklink` can only create it on a NTFS filesystem (and maybe ReFS, I don't have experience with that).

A remote filesystem (especially one that is served by a unix system) is not NTFS, so it can't create a symlink there.

Sadly, the [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) lacks any information about that, but the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) is pretty detailed.